# django translation(?) in templates

Tags: django, django-templates, translation

I put a (?) after translation because I'm not sure if this is a translation issue or not.

I have a UserProfile model that looks like so:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model) :
GENDER_CHOICES = (('M', _('Male')),
                  ('F', _('Female')))
gender = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
```

as well as a corresponding UserProfileModelForm. When I display said form using `form.as_p` the Gender field is shown as a drop-down selection and it displays "Male" and "Female."

Now I want to show the same words in my Profile Detail template, but when I do `{{ profile.gender }}` the letters "M" and "F" are displayed. This is as expected of course, because that is what's recorded in the database. But how do I make my Profile Detail template show "Male" and "Female" as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `{{ profile.get_gender_display }}` See the [docs here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display)